# how to create rest service in nativescript angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, nativescript

please help me to create rest service in nativescript angular.

this my rest client address: http://api.bagi2.com/user
authentication : Basic a2V5RHJpdmVyQXBwOk1vdmVUb090aGVyTW92ZQ==

i try this docs https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/http, but i can't view data.

anyone can recomended e-book or help me to leard binding data in nativescript angular all. please :(

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a service where you put all the calls for your api. You could use `httpModule` to call your api and put it inside a promise to catch errors.

example: `my-api.service.ts` and class name is `MyService`

```
getUser() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        httpModule.request({
           url: 'http://api.bagi2.com/user',
           method: 'GET'
        }).then((res) => {
            resolve(res)
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err)
        })
    })

    return promise;
}
```

and inject it to your component ts file.
example: `app.component.ts`

```
// assume you know how to import files
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
     this.myService.getUser()
         .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
         }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err) 
         })
}
```